# subtitude keys and values in TreeMap with other TreeMap in Java

Tags: java, treemap

Assuming I have a `TreeMap<String,List<String> first;` and `TreeMap<String,String> Origin;` And each key and each value in first has an equivalent key in origin.  How can I substitute key and values of first with related value from Origin? For example

```
first {a = [b,c,d], e = [ f,g,h]}
origin {a=a1,b=b1,c=c1,d=d1,e = e1, g = g1, h=h1}
```

I need to get this TreeMap
    DesiredMap  {[a1 =b1,c1,d1],[e1 = f1,g1,h1]}

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. If you're question is: "How do I do this?" we'll tell you (a) Please try it first and post what you tried, and (b) your question is written is too broad

Comment: BTW this is MUCH MUCH easier to accomplish in Javascript using JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over the entries on your `first` TreeMap.

```
for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : first.entrySet()) {
```

For each `entry` grab the `oldKey` and the `oldValues`.

```
String oldKey= entry.getKey();
List<String> oldValues= entry.getValue();
```

Create the `newKey`

```
String newKey = origin.get(oldKey);
```

Then iterate over each value `s` in `oldValues` to get the newValue from the `origin` in order to create the List of `newValues`

```
List<String> newValues = new ArrayList<>();
for(String s : oldValues) {
    newValues.add(origin.get(s));
}
```

Now that you have the `newKey` and the `newValues` put them in your `result` TreeMap.

```
result.put(newKey, newValues);
```

Go to the next `entry` and repeat!